# Newman call returns ssl3_read_bytes alert handshake failure

Tags: ssl, openssl, postman, newman

Using Newman to run a collection, I am seeing the following error:

```
GET https://aai-udev02.dev.att.com:8443/narad/v1/common/policies/policy/f74133af-e758-4e63-9eab-caf37acfc6f4?depth=2 [errored]
write EPROTO 140736015946624:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1407:SSL alert number 40
```

I'm not sure where this error is coming from, nor how to fix it. Have any Newman users seen this error in the past? Note, I'm also working behind a proxy (not sure if it has anything to do with this error).

Comment: What command are you using to run Newman?

Comment: I'm using: newman run -d <data-source> <collections.json file>

Comment: The collection file probably needs to be at the start before the data file but that's a different thing. Have you tried adding the `-k` flag to the end and running it?

Comment: Yup, tried -k and --insecure, but no luck unfortunately. Still seeing the same error

Comment: In addition to the above, which Node version are you performing the `newman run ...` command on? Also, does the endpoint in question require/go through a proxy?